# The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again. Magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, database

I installed magento 2.4.0 on my Linux server from godaddy. I'm unable to add the products to it. It is showing the Error is The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again. Can any one help me from this please[image]